# Cisco RV220W - No route to host between devices on the same subnet

Tags: cisco, routing

I have a problem where devices cannot connect to each other using their respective IP addresses, but if a device uses it's own IP address it can connect.  When you try and connect to a remote device you get a no route to host.  Pinging the device by their IP address also doesn't work.  The router is configured to use half duplex and we have 3 access points configured on it.  The devices are connected on the same wifi access point so they should be able to see each other.

So any ideas on what is preventing devices from seeing each other?

Comment: Is default gateway set, and it is correct? Can You ping each device from router?

Comment: Default gateway is set to 10.1.10.1 and our devices are 10.1.10.*.  Traffic to the internet works fine.  And the router can ping the devices.

Answer (score 1):

Check your access point for a 'Wireless Separation' option.
Some access points are configured by default to restrict traffic between wireless devices.